# Meaning of "blatant plug"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> In a blatant plug for the Reagent Guide, each Friday  I profile a
>   different reagent that is commonly encountered in Org 1/ Org 2.

What is the meaning of "blatant plug". here ? I searched the net but could't find its meaning.

Source http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/12/09/reagent-friday-zinc-amalgam-zn-hg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Plugging](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plug)*** (informal) refers to the act promoting one's own work/ another person's work in Social media or over the Internet.

> *Informal*. the favorable mention of something, as in a lecture, radio show, etc.; advertisement; recommendation

[Merriam-Webster, sense 8]

In this particular case, the author seems to be doing different chemical experiments on every Friday, exclusively (blatantly) in order to promote or garner visibility for the *Reagent Guide* and the *Reagent App*.